# NSOpenPanel runModalforTypes

Tags: cocoa, nsopenpanel

I got this code from the book Core Animation from Zarra/Long.  It will not compile due to the following error:  "'runModalForTypes' is deprecated"

```
- (IBAction)setMovieLocation:(id)sender {
NSOpenPanel *openPanel;

openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories: NO];
[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection: NO];
[openPanel setResolvesAliases: NO];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles: NO];

if ([openPanel runModalForTypes:nil] == NSOKButton)
{
    [[qcLayer setValue:openPanel filename]
     forInputKey:[@"movie_location" ;]]
}
}
```

Is there a possible fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a `NSOpenPanel` inherits from `NSSavePanel`, you'll find this method suited:

```
if ([openPanel runModal] == NSOKButton)
```

See documentation for [NSSavePanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000309-BAJBGAAJ) and [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsopenpanel_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000308-BAJCHEJG)

Comment: @user3432279 you're welcome. If you'd be so kind to check my answer as accepted using the mark left hand right below the arrows :-)